# RestKit mapping with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, restkit

In Rails 3.0.8 the json contains a root  element with your model name.  For example my Location model.

```
[
{
location: {
city: San Diego
name: Mission Valley YMCA Krause Family Skatepark
pads_required: 0
country: United States
```

And the mapping provider looked directly for the location object.

```
RKObjectMapping* locationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKLocation class]];   
[locationMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"locationId"];
...
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:locationMapping forKeyPath:@"location"];
```

Now when you upgrade to rails 3.1.0 the root node "location" is now removed by default  and I'm not sure how to configure the mapping provider without it?  I tried nil and looked for alternative methods but was unsuccessful.

Do you know how to map this?  Please help!

```
[
{
   city: San Diego
   name: Mission Valley YMCA Krause Family Skatepark
   pads_required: 0
   country: United States
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the RestKit side, I don't know, but from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515436/rails-3-1-include-root-in-json) it looks like you can get the json back to what RestKit expects by doing:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.include_root_in_json = true
end
```

Edit:
For completeness, here's how you'd do it with RestKit:

```
RKObjectMapping* locationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKLocation class]];   
[locationMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"locationId"];
...
[objectManager.mappingProvider addObjectMapping:locationMapping];
```

And then calling the mapper later:

```
RKObjectMapping* locationMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[RKLocation class]];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/locations" objectMapping:locationMapping delegate:self];
```

And then you'd handle the objects in RKObjectLoader delegate methods.

Answer (score 4):

In RestKit, you can register a mapping to contain a root model name like this:

```
[objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:locationMapping withRootKeyPath:@"location"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet answer: `forKeyPath:@""` will work.