# Setting properties on ActiveModel::Base from an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

Content of initializers/rails_defaults.rb

```
ActiveModel::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

The error I get on startup:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Base
```

Anyone know of a remedy?

*I'm using rails 3.1.RC4.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 2.x? Change `ActiveModel` to `ActiveRecord`, and look in  `initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb` for the setting.

See:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

Rails 3? Looks like for now you set it in the model directly instead:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.include_root_in_json = true
end
```

Edit:
You may also want to look at this:
[Rails 3.1 include_root_in_json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515436/rails-3-1-include-root-in-json)

Comment: Thanks! I should've mentioned that I use Rails 3.1. So it is the linked property I'm trying to use. (I think) the problem is that ActiveModel isn't available in the initializer for some reason.