# Rails: Disable root in JSON for only specific controller actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, activerecord

I know how to disable the root element globally, a la [Rails 3.1 include_root_in_json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515436/rails-3-1-include-root-in-json) or by using `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false`, but I only want to do this for a few JSON requests (not globally).

So far, I've been doing it like this:

```
@donuts = Donut.where(:jelly => true)
@coffees = Coffee.all
@breakfast_sandwiches = Sandwich.where(:breakfast => true)

dunkin_donuts_order = {}
dunkin_donuts_order[:donuts] = @donuts
dunkin_donuts_order[:libations] = @coffees
dunkin_donuts_order[:non_donut_food] = @breakfast_sandwiches

Donut.include_root_in_json = false
Coffee.include_root_in_json = false

render :json => dunkin_donuts_order

Donut.include_root_in_json = true
Coffee.include_root_in_json = true
```

There are about 5 cases where I have to do this, sometimes with more than one model, and it doesn't feel clean at all. I had tried putting this in `around_filter`s, but exceptions were breaking the flow, and that was getting hairy as well.

There must be a better way!

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but it does answer the one I came here looking for: You CAN suppress the root on individual calls to `to_json`, e.g. `Donut.to_json(root: false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, unfortunately, yes and no.

Yes, what you've done above can arguably be done better. No, Rails won't let you add the root on a per-action basis. The JSON rendering just wasn't built with that sort of flexibility in mind.

That being said, here's what I'd do:

1. Set `include_root_in_json` to `false` for those models which have root depending on the action (such as `Donut` and `Coffee` above).
2. Override `as_json` to allow for greater flexibility. Here's an example:

   ```
   # in model.rb
   def as_json(options = nil)
       hash = serializable_hash(options)
       if options && options[:root]
           hash = { options[:root] => hash }
       else
           hash = hash
       end
   end
   ```

   This example will make it so that you can optionally pass a root but defaults to no root. You could alternatively write it the other way.
3. Since you overrode `as_json`, you'll have to modify your render calls appropriately. So, for `Donut`, you'd do `render :json => @donut.to_json`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I stopped shooting myself in the foot and switched to [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) and have never looked back. So much better!

Comment: Good answer. but you don't have to call as_json().to_json because to_json automatically calls your as_json override.

Comment: Thanks, @NadaAldahleh. I've clarified that bit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `include_root_in_json` per model **instance**, and it won't affect the class's (see `class_attribute` in the rails api for a description of this behavior). So you can set a sensible default value on the class level, then set a different value on each instance in the relevant controllers.

Example:

```
@donuts = Donut.where(:jelly => true).each {|d| d.include_root_in_json = false }
```

For convenience, you can create a utility method that accepts an array of model instances and sets the value on all of them.