# Is there a cleaner way of giving a JSON object a named root?

Tags: ruby, json, ember.js, jsonp

I need to give this object a named root before serving it up, is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
get '/api/ducks/:id' do |id|
    content_type :json
    duck = {
        duck: Duck.find(id)
    }
    JSONP duck
end
```

Comment: I don't know what you're using server side, but perhaps in your environnement you can have something like https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what orm you are using

Assuming you are using active-record

you can set 
    some where in config which applies globaly

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
```

or

```
Duck.find(id).as_json(:root=>true)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Check this SO answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/6515973/518832

> For MongoMapper

```
class Something
  include MongoMapper::Document
  self.include_root_in_json = true
end
```

and then

```
JSONP Duck.where(:id=>id).to_json
```

should work as per this github comment
https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/issues/392

also you would like to check the source how it works just for knowledge

https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/serialization.rb

Comment: I'm using Rails and MongoMapper, so no - not using ActiveRecord.

Comment: @ZenSavona I have updated my answer for MongoMapper hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for that, upvoted.

It still doesn't really do what I need though, as Ember requires a single plural root for the /api/ducks and a single singular root for /api/ducks/:id, where this creates a singular named root for each question, regardless of what query is run (Duck.all or Duck.find)

Comment: @ZenSavona have updated my answer with where clause i have not used mongomapper let me know if it works

Answer (score 2):

The only cleaner way is to remove the unneeded variable:

```
get '/api/ducks/:id' do |id|
    content_type :json
    JSONP { duck: Duck.find(id) }
end
```